Parsing floating point number to a uint64_t fails with fast-math
I have some code that parses floating point number and returns an unsigned int if the number can be converted to unsigned without losing precision:
#include <charconv>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdint.h>

// Note: the source number is expected to be within 32-bit UINT_MAX range, not full 64-bit range.
uint64_t read_uint(std::string_view num)
{
    double d;
    auto r = std::from_chars(num.data(), num.data() + num.size(), d);
    if (r.ec == std::errc() && r.ptr == num.data() + num.size())
    {
        uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d;
        if (d == u + 0.0) // conversion back to a double produced identical value
            return u;
    }
    return ~0ull; // error, return -1
}

and the expectations are:
assert(read_uint("1.0") == 1);
assert(read_uint("1.0654553e+07") == 10654553);
assert(read_uint("1.1") == ~0ull);  // error
assert(read_uint("-123") == ~0ull); // error

However, this code fails miserably with clang on x64/x86 optimized builds when targeting avx/avx2/avx512 and using -fast-math. Specifically, parsing negative numbers fails: assert(read_uint("-123") == ~0llu); Instead of returning -1, it actually returns -123 (converted to uint64_t). The reason it fails is because conversion back to double to verify that the result is identical produces different result:
        uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d;
        if (d == u + 0.0)  // u + 0.0 produces different result
            return u;

as a side note, casting also produces different value when targeting avx512:
        uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d; // u might not be exact when targeting avx512

Clearly, this code is riddled with bugs and gotchas and I have some questions:

What are the issues with it, are there any UBs? (ignoring obvious stuff like underlying uint64_t might not be representable by a double)
Why is it uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d produces different result with fast-math and avx512?
Why is it u + 0.0 produces different result with fast-math and avxN?
What should be a proper approach here?
Is there a compile time flag to identify such possible cases in code?

Note, that with MS compiler I haven't seen any of the issues above. Values are always exact/identical regardless of optimizations, floating point model, or target arch.
As a side note, this is not exact code that's used in prod, but some extract from it. It parses numbers returned by polygon.io json APIs. Perhaps, they carelessly dumped numbers using python and I've seen cases where values were something like "1.0", "1.0654553e+07" etc in place of plain integers. So far, as a simple workaround I changed casting to uint64_t to be:
uint64_t u = (uint64_t)fabs(d);

Minimal example: https://godbolt.org/z/cKzrK6ven (if you remove -O2 from clang cmdline output will change)
Update.
it appears that casting to int64_t first is the most optimal solution: https://godbolt.org/z/cjjzPMPrh
uint64_t u = (uint64_t)(int64_t)d;


OT: In C++, whenever you feel the need to do a C-style explicit conversion (a cast) then you should take that as a sign that you're probably is doing something wrong. Use the standard C++ conversion operators, like static_cast, instead.

As for your problem, that has the smell of undefined behavior. What and where I don't know. And have you tried to look at the generated assembly code to see what's actually is happening?

return ~0llu; why so fancy? You can simply return -1; it wil be correctly converted to the right unsigned value

@463035818_is_not_an_ai return -1 is a warning (error) in my project. I think I have something like ~uint64_t{} in actual code. Basically, the code returns all bits set to 1

@Someprogrammerdude static_cast doesn't make it less UB though, just makes it easy to search for the casts. I didn't check generated asm.

"static_cast doesn't make it less UB though, just makes it easy to search for the casts." not correct. There are many ways a c-style cast can silently go wrong where a static_cast produces a nice error

Can you please share how exactly you run this test? I can't reproduce your results.

I cannot reproduce either. Please post a [mcve]

Re: return ~0llu; // error, return -1 -- it's ironic that you have to write a comment to explain the code that you wrote because the compiler insisted that you weren't smart enough to understand the (clear, well-defined) code that you originally wrote.

Minor style point: l and 1 can look very much alike; constants like 0llu really should be written 0ull.

@PeteBecker, ~0 (or ~0ull) is the actual intended code (all bits set to 1), while -1 simply happens to do exactly that. I simply wrote it here so that some ppl wouldn't bother trying to guess what it meant. Actual code has ~uint64_t{} or something like that. Good point for 0ull, code updated.

@FrançoisAndrieux post has minimal example link

@463035818_is_not_an_ai minimal example:  https://godbolt.org/z/cKzrK6ven where does static_cast produce error? The minimal example actually uses static_cast

without  +0.0 its the same effect with -fast-math https://godbolt.org/z/PTMWx97Gr

+0.0 converts to double. Without it, perhaps left side gets converted to uint, which is clearly wrong

fast-math allows the compiler to break some language rules to generate faster code, so you can get incorrect results in some cases and surprising results in others, you can also get straight up incorrect code. If you are ok with that and it works for you; fine, but in most cases I'd advise to stay away from it so you can rely on the guarantees that the C++ standard provides and actually know how your program will behave.

@PavelP Your update/solution belongs in its own answer.  Best to revert this question and put it there.

@PavelP Do you expect read_uint("-123") to return ~0ull?  If not, what uint64_t value?

@chux yes, -123 isn't a non-negative integer.

Yes, your code has undefined behavior.
N4928 conv.fpint p1

A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented
in the destination type.

The truncated value is -123, which cannot be represented in the destination type uint64_t (it can only represent nonnegative values) so this is undefined behavior.
Note this applies whether you use a C-style cast (uint64_t)d or static_cast<uint64_t>(d).
It's true that converting a value of integer type with the value -123 to uint64_t yields a well-defined result (namely 2^64 - 123 = 18446744073709551493).  But this does not apply when converting a value of floating-point type.

I mentioned this part in the msg: “ ignoring obvious stuff like underlying uint64_t might not be representable by a double”. In the example, -123 has no issues with underlying representation

Ah, ok, I see. At the end of your message this is explained. I actually solved it with fabs(d) before casting to uint64_t. This part takes care of the UB

Alternative way is to cast to int64_t and then to uint64_t

Yeah, it's the other way around.  It's not that the uint64_t can't be represented exactly by a double, but that the double can't be represented by uint64_t.

@PavelP: Safer might be to check d >= 0 && d <= std::numeric_limits<std::uint64_t>::max().

Since I parse, I can simply check first char to be ‘-‘, lots of solutions, but I wanted to understand what was wrong. Your answer made it clear

Seems like casting to int64_t and then to uint64_t is the optimal solution: https://godbolt.org/z/cjjzPMPrh

@PavelP: You've still got UB if the value is out of range of int64_t though, e.g 99999999999999999999999 or 1.7e+26. Or Inf or NaN for that matter.

In the question it's stated ignoring obvious stuff like underlying uint64_t might not be representable by a double. Basically, my code assumes that polygon.io api serves legit numbers and not some garbage. In any case, with UB it will most likely return ~0 anyways. Also, my code actually expects numbers within UINT_MAX, uint64_t is used for internal computation.

Those sound to me like unsafe assumptions - but, your code, your funeral.

A range test is needed first as uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d; and (uint64_t)(int64_t)d both have undefined behavior (UB) if d is far outside the uint64_t/int64_t range.
Instead of
        uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d;
        if (d == u + 0.0) // conversion back to a double produced identical value
            return u;

Range*1 test first:
    #define TWO_POWER_64  18446744073709551616.0
    if (u >= 0.0 && u < TWO_POWER_64) {
      uint64_t u = (uint64_t)d;
      if (d == u + 0.0) {
        return u;
      }
    } 

Pedantic code may want to test for NAN:
    if (!isnan(u) && (u > -1.0 && u < TWO_POWER_64)) {


Alternative fraction test
Rather than cast back to double and compare, consider a direct fraction test.
    #define TWO_POWER_64  18446744073709551616.0
    double ipart;
    if (!isnan(u) && u >= 0.0 && u < TWO_POWER_64 && modf(d,&ipart) == 0.0) {
      return (uint64_t) d;
    } 


*1  The range of valid double with an uint64_t cast is -0.9999... to just less than 264.  Since any value with a fraction should "fail" read_uint(), code can use u >= 0.0 (inclusive) as a lower bound rather than u > -1.0.
Note that -0.0 successfully returns 0, so a sign test is not good.
Code does not use 18446744073709551615.0 as the upper bound.  That decimal constant form may incur implementation defined behavior (IDB) due to having more precision (63 bit) than the common double (53 bit).  So let us avoid IDB.
    // Weak code
    #define TWO_POWER_64_M1  18446744073709551615.0
    if (u >= 0.0 && u <= TWO_POWER_64_M1) {


This won't work correctly. If I had such requirement to make it work correctly, then a way to make it work is to check if the result is less than safe interger (which is 2^53-1 == 9007199254740991). Anything above it, isn't guaranteed to be representable. For example, check 2^53 read_uint("9007199254740992") and read_uint("9007199254740993"), both will return 2^53.

@PavelP,  with common double it is true that not every uint64_t value between [2^53 and 2^64) is representable as a double.  Yet this code here does work for those whole number double values in that range - guaranteed.  Try "9007199254740994".  (2^53+2)

only some numbers work, but most numbers do not work above 2^53
https://godbolt.org/z/33bMsrEqv

also, this is all pointless, my actual code first does std::from_chars for uint64_t, and tries to parse as double if the source isn't parsable as a uint64_t. I omitted it because only the double conversion was problematic.

@PavelP this is all pointless, --> best to post relevant conditions in the question.

questions are listed in the message, first one mentions this:  ... ignoring obvious stuff like underlying uint64_t might not be representable by a double

@PavelP Based on your "9007199254740993" comment, it sounded to me that you no longer wanted to ignore uint64_t might not be representable by a double.  Now it sounds like you want to set that range of values aside.  OK.

if you follow question, it specifically says to ignore obvious stuff like uint64_t might not be representable by a double. Everything else is irrelevant. Discussion went into parts that aren't part of the question, I pointed out issues with proposed solution. That's all. My actual code does use safe integer check to ensure representable range, but the question is about numbers within representable range.

Accepted answer has exactly what I was looking for: The truncated value is -123, which cannot be represented in the destination type uint64_t (it can only represent nonnegative values) so this is undefined behavior. Simple as that.

Your answer basically starts from answering something that's irrelevant to the question. Question was specifically ONLY for numbers within representable range. I stripped out my code from all the things that handle valid ranges, and posted relevant part where numbers within range seemed to fail sometimes with some compilers. My mistake was that I assumed that -123.0 was within range of uint64_t (which doesn't work for double -> uint64_t)
